# Calculating Average Weekly Traffic in Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I've got a table in Google Data Studio showing monthly traffic numbers and I would like to have another table that shows average weekly traffic based on the monthly numbers in another table on the same page.

Having some trouble figuring out the custom calculated field formula for this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Provide examples of what you did and what already works (code and screenshots) and you'll probably get help. with your current question it would mostly be guessing.

Comment: At the moment, I've got a table that's pulling through monthly traffic numbers for year to date. So one column has each month of 2018 and the other has that month's traffic.

Previously, I had all of this sitting in a spreadsheet, with the figures input manually and then a formula to work out the weekly average based on that month's total: =SUM(X / 4.34)

I tried pulling that sheet into Data Studio, but it gives me errors each time. I tried automating the data pull and then using a formula, same errors.

Is it possible to create a formula in Data Studio directly?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me.

```
SUM(Sales)/COUNT_DISTINCT((EXTRACT(ISOWEEK from DATE)))
```

Answer (score 0):

From your example, is it not as easy as your monthly traffic numbers / 4.34?

Comment: Sure, but attempts to recreate that formula in Data Studio has so far proved unsuccessful. So I'm seeking some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to present this, there's a pretty easy, and decent solution - [Reference Lines](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9921462?hl=en).

Using a reference line, you can chart weekly values (ie: weekly sessions) on a bar chart, then via a reference line, you can plot 1 line for the average of that period (all the bars currently present). Because it is native to the visualization it will recalculate as you you filter!

[image: Example of a Reference Line in Action!]